# Which manga chapters are covered by both season of Kamisama Hajimemashita anime?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

Which manga chapters are covered by both season of *Kamisama Hajimemashita* anime?

Alternatively, if I am to pick up the story where the anime left off, what chapter should I begin reading?

Answer (score 5):

The second season ending covers the events of the manga up to chapter 64.

The first season ends at chapter 30 or 31 (you can think of chapter 31 as a transition).

Notable differences:

> The earth spider at the end of season 1 is anime-only. Also Nanami ends the Kagura dance without Mikage's interference.

and:

> Kayako the human-goddess is manga-only. She is Nanami's rival for the vacant spot at the Izumo's god summit.

There are some other scenes from past chapters covering the new year's transition event,

> Like the swamp princess wedding preparation and the Tengu visit to Kurama on Earth

but they are minor details, and there are already a side-story on chapters 65 and 66, so it is better to pin the ending of the second season on chapter 64.

Answer (score 0):

The Kamisama Hajimemashita anime has a first season which consists of 13 episodes; after that is the second season which consists of 12 episodes to be followed by OVA entitled "Kamisama Hajimemashita: Kako-hen," which consists of 4 episodes. If you are curious about the events after the last episode of the OVA, then you start to read the manga in Chapter 101 up to 149.